# Travis CI Database with Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, travis-ci

I am currently trying to set up Travis CI for my Spring application. I have the builds running, but they are failing due to a failure to connect to the test database on Travis. For context, I am setting the datasource in this config file. The connection arguments are set via environment variables.

```
@Configuration
```

`public class DatasourceConfig {`

```
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver";

        /*Create the datasource and return it*/
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url( url )
                .username( username )
                .password( password )
                .driverClassName( driverClassName )
                .build();
    } }
```

My question is that, assuming I set up a postgres database on Travis CI and leave it with the default setup, what would be the values for the the datasource url, username, and password? I was unable to find in their docs where I can find this information. Also, for some more context, here is my .travis.yml file.

`language: java
jdk:
 - oraclejdk8
services:
   - postgresql
before_script:
   - psql -c 'create database friend_status_test;' -U postgres`

Comment: Why not use in memory database for testing?

Comment: Great point. I set up an h2 database and that solved the problem.